# How can I explicitly show the return value of a code snippet/sample

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-formatting, best-practices, stack-snippets

Is there an commonly accepted way (best practice if you wish) to show the return value of example code in markdown?

One solution is to add a comment at the end of the function, but I am concerned that this adds unnecessary text when people are copy-pasting, especially when the snippet is multiple lines long.

```js
String.fromCharCode(parseInt("ff", 16)) // returns ÿ
```

I think this is usually a good situation for [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) instead of Code Sample. However, sometimes you will still want to explicitly show the return value.

If you were referencing the return value interspersed with regular text, would it be appropriate to format the return value as inline code, e.g.

"The following function takes the hex number `ff` and returns the character `ÿ`"?

Comment: I don't believe there is "best practice". Use what you prefer and you find easier to understand. The specifics will vary a lot among languages, frameworks,etc.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs This is a question about formatting markdown and not specific to any language or site. Could you clarify why this is off-topic for Meta?

Comment: @Bitterdreggs Also, do you think I should ask the paragraph at the bottom as a separate question? It is more specific (yes/no) about whether to use the Code Sample tag inline to reference a return value. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: This question might be better off on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) but it's certainly not blatantly off-topic.

Comment: @rene I am thinking of breaking this question into two. The first part of this question I would ask again in a more open-ended way. I am just curious how others write/format their answers. What made me think of this is how to avoid unnecessary text when writing a snippet that will be copy-pasted by many people.

Comment: @rene Second, "Is it appropriate to use Code Sample formatting if the text is technically not code?" I want to know if the bottom example in this question would be better if I highlighted the text bold or some other way.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks, I actually forgot about Meta Stack Overflow. I think it fits my question a little better. What do you think about my previous comments to @rene? Should I repost it as two questions there?